# Find a probability such that all (not trivial) events are dependent.

Tags: probability-theory, independence

**Question :**

> Let's be $\Omega$ a finite set ($|\Omega |\geqslant 2$). Find a probability on $(\Omega, \mathcal{P}(\Omega))$ such that for all $(A,B)$ element of $(P(\Omega) \backslash \{ \emptyset, \Omega\})^2$, $A$ and $B$ are dependent.

**My Attempt :**

If we look at uniform probability, we easily get that it verifies the property if and only if the $|\Omega|$ is prime (if not we can take $A$ and $B$ such that $|A\cap B|=1$ and $|A|=p$, $|B|=q$ where $n=pq$)

Then if it is not the case, what I thought is I could modify this probability a bit. But the problem is I must keep the probability of all events (except $\emptyset$ of course) not null. I can't see how to make it.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $|\Omega |=n$ and let $P$ be a  prime such that $p_1+p_2+...+p_n=P$ is a sum of positive integers.

Let $p_i/P$ be the probability of the sample space points.

Voila!